# operator does not exist: bigint = bytea

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

Here is my code:

```java
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
ids.add(10L);
ids.add(11L);

SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(
        "select type_id from Types where parent_type_id in (:typeIds)");

sqlQuery.setParameter("typeIds", ids);
List<Object[]> results = sqlQuery.list();
```

I am getting this error while executing the above query.
FYI, I just saw this issue when I passed an array or ArrayList as paramter.

```
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter: ERROR: operator does not exist:
bigint = bytea Exception in thread "main"
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
```

Comment: query.setParameterList("typeIds",ids);
it got resolved :)

Comment: Post it as answer and accept it. So everybody can see it's resolved right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```java
query.setParameterList("typeIds", ids);
```

It got resolved using `setParameterList();`

Answer (score 4):

You will get this same error if `null == ids`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, this error occurs when one of the items in the list is `NULL`.